# Flashing BIOS under DOS

Tags: laptop, bios

I've got a bootable USB stick with a particular flavor of DOS. I need to flash a BIOS of a [Compaq Presario CQ61-330EN](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4062&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=4064517#N438).

The problem is, however, that I can not flash under Windows (for circumstantial reasons), but forced to do it under DOS and Compaq does not provide any utility that can be ran under DOS.

I can't see to identify the manufacturer of BIOS – neither does Compaq/HP's site mention it. There's only an `.fd` file in the bundled archive provided on site (plus a Win32 utility).

Can anyone recommend a DOS-compatible flashing utility and, most importantly, will it work with ANY type of BIOS? Like, i.e., would it still be feasible to flash either an Award or a Phoenix BIOS with such an util or is it usually bound to a manufacturer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in a bit of a bind in that those BIOS updates MUST be run from within Windows. I would ONLY use this method.

Now, to get around your lack of Windows, I would probably recommend one of the following methods:

1. Watch this video on how to install XP on a USB drive, and boot to that: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=re1_ude0fhE
2. Borrow an empty drive, and swap it out. Do a quick OS install and run the update from there.
3. Use [Easeus Partition Manger](http://www.easeus.com/download.htm) to resize, and create an empty partition AFTER your current partition. Then install Windows there.

Then do your update.

I would choose two as easiest.

Answer (score 1):

I would **strongly** advise you use the manufacturer recommended method. A third party **BIOS flashing** tool isn't necessarily you want to go looking for.  There are just too many unknowns and jacking up your BIOS means your laptop is now a heavy paperweight.

Answer (score 0):

Try BartPE, or some other LiveCD version of Windows.